# Pulling from BitBucket to server makes file group permissions 0 0

Tags: linux, git, permissions, centos, bitbucket

I just setup Git to pull from bitbucket onto our staging server and then upon testing the site was giving a 500 error.

Investigating the matter showed that many files including the `index.php` file now had group permissions of `0 0` and everything else in the folder is `504 503`.

How can I fix this so it doesn't change the permissions / sets them properly?

Answer (score 0):

Git does not track file permissions.

You can set a config variable to track it if needed (will be considered a change)

```
# consider chmod changes as a "real" change
git config core.filemode true
```

You can also run update index command with the --chmod flag to set te desired permissions on your files.

> ***`--chmod=(+|-)x`***
>
> Set the execute permissions on the updated files.
> `git update-index --chmod=+x`

Comment: Well I don't actually want to *track* permission changes and that is why I have set `filemode` to `false`; I just want it to not change the file permissions or set them correctly and not to `0 0`.